# LINQ to Objects - Does Not Contain?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of Items that each have a collection of Relationships.  I have a list of Groups that Items can have Relationships with.

I can find all the Items that have a particular relationship but I now want to find all the Items that don't have a Relationship with any of my Groups.

I can find the Items that have a relationship with any of the Groups by doing this:

```
Dim groupIds as List(of Integer) = (From g In cmdbGroups Select g.ID).ToList
Dim haveGroup = (From item In items _
                 Where item.Relationships.Any(Function(r) groupIds.Contains(r.TargetID)) _
                 Select item).ToList
```

How can I find all the items that do not have a relationship with any of the groups?

Comment: Don't you just want to negate the where clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember VB all that well, but a simple "Not" should work.

```
Dim groupIds as List(of Integer) = (From g In cmdbGroups Select g.ID).ToList
Dim haveGroup = (From item In items _
             Where Not item.Relationships.Any(Function(r) groupIds.Contains(r.TargetID)) _
             Select item).ToList
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried negating the results of the `Contains` method?

```
Dim groupIds as List(of Integer) = (From g In cmdbGroups Select g.ID).ToList
Dim haveGroup = (From item In items _
                 Where item.Relationships.Any(Function(r) Not groupIds.Contains(r.TargetID)) _
                 Select item).ToList
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This matches all items that have one or more Relationships that don't match, as opposed to all items that have no matching Relationships.

Comment: This was what I had originally tried, but as Thorarin correctly points out, it returned all of the items in the original group rather than excluding those with any matches.

Answer (score 2):

If you're generating the `haveGroup` collection anyway then you could just do something like this:

```
Dim groupIds as List(of Integer) = (From g In cmdbGroups Select g.ID).ToList

Dim haveGroup = (From item In items _
    Where item.Relationships.Any(Function(r) groupIds.Contains(r.TargetID)) _
    Select item).ToList

Dim haveNotGroup = items.Except(haveGroup).ToList
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim notHasGroup = items.Except(haveGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim listIds as List(of Integer) = (From g In cmdbGroups Select g.ID).ToList
Dim haveGroup = (From item In items _
    Where Not listIds.Contains(item.ID) 
    Select item.ID).ToList
```

Comment: Can you please add an explenation to your answer?